# Presto Nodes with too much load

Tags: hive, hortonworks-data-platform, presto, bigdata

I'm performing some queries over a tpch 100gb dataset on presto, I have 4 nodes, 1 master, 3 workers. When I try to run some queries, not all of them, I see on Presto web interface that the nodes die during the execution, resulting in query failure, the error is the following:

> .facebook.presto.operator.PageTransportTimeoutException: Encountered too many errors talking to a worker node. The node may have crashed or been under too much load. This is probably a transient issue, so please retry your query in a few minutes.

I rebooted all nodes and presto service but the error remains, this problem doesn't exist if I run the same queries over a smaller dataset.Can someone provide some help on this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

3 possible causes for this kind of error. You may ssh into one of worker to find out what the problem is when the query is running.

- High CPU

  Tune down the `task.concurrency` to, for example, 8
- High memory

  In the `jvm.config`, `-Xmx` should no more than 80% total memory. In the `config.properties`, `query.max-memory-per-node` should be no more than the half of `Xmx` number.
- Low open file limit

  Set in the `/etc/security/limits.conf` a larger number for the Presto process. The default is definitely way too low.

Answer (score 0):

It might be an issue for configuration. For example, if the local maximum memory is not set appropriately and the query use too much heap memory, full GC might happen to cause such errors. I would suggest to ask in the Presto Google Group and describe someway to reproduce the issue :)

Answer (score 0):

I was running presto on Mac with 16GB of ram below is the configuration of java.config file.

```
-server
-Xmx16G
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:G1HeapRegionSize=32M
-XX:+UseGCOverheadLimit
-XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrent
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=kill -9 %p
```

I was getting following error even for running the Query

Select now();

```
Query 20200817_134204_00005_ud7tk failed: Encountered too many errors talking to a worker node. The node may have crashed or be under too much load. This is probably a transient issue, so please retry your query in a few minutes.
```

I changed my -Xmx16G value to -Xmx10G and it works fine.

I used following link to install presto on my system.

[Link for Presto Installation](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/apache_presto/apache_presto_installation.htm)

Comment: With this change, the node may fail to start because of the following error (/mnt/var/log/presto/server.log): Invalid memory configuration. The sum of max total query memory per node (7839174309) and heap headroom (3073631846) cannot be larger than the available heap memory (10245439488). Check the official document to solve this: https://prestodb.io/docs/current/admin/properties.html#query-max-total-memory-per-node